# Send messages between apps within same browser window

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom

I have two separate web apps, an angular parent app and a react child app. The parent app is loading the child app in an iframe. I am trying to have these apps talk to each other using `window.postMessage()` but either the message isn't being properly sent or it isn't being received.

Here is exactly what I've tried.

Parent App:

```
window.postMessage(message, "*")
```

Child App:

```
window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
     console.log(event)
}
```

The only thing I have to go off of is when I console log the window on the parent, I see:

```
postMessage: f postMessage: ()
   length: 1
   name: "postMessage"
   arguments: [Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not 
               be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to       
               them at Function.s (<anonymous>:1:83)]
   caller: [Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not 
               be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to       
               them at Function.s (<anonymous>:1:83)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parent must dispatch the message from the `window` of the target (child process, iframe in your case) not from the `window` object of the parent:

```
const child = document.querySelector('iframe').contentWindow;
child.postMessage(message, "*")
```